# Qt ListWidget icon's color changed because of background color

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, qtstylesheets

This question might be a little complicated to understand...

Let's say you have a QListWidget with blue icons. When you click on any items inside the QListWidget, the item will be highlighted with blue background color(the exact color identical to the color of the icons). In this way, the icon will be invisible because all you will see is blue.

[image: This is the very QListWidget I am talking about]

[image: When you select any item, it will be highlighted with color blue]

So in order to see the icon when the item is clicked and highlighted, I have to invert the color of the icon when clicked. My solution is to make another icon identical to the previous one but with white color. So when the item is clicked, the icon is supposed to turn white so that we could see the icon clearly. However, things go sideways and all we see is that:

[image: The icon is not absolute white, instead it is light blue]

I cannot understand why the icon is light blue when it is supposed to be white. Here are the two different color of icons I am talking about. They are in .png format.

[image: the blue icon and the white icon]

Additional information: in order to highlight the item when clicked, I used QSS. The code is as the following:

```
    QListWidget 
    {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        border-raduis: 10px;
        font: 10.5pt "Microsoft Yahei";
        outline: 0px;
        padding-top: 55px;
    }
    QListWidget::item 
    {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #000000;
        border: 0px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        height: 38px;
    }
    QListWidget::item:selected 
    {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: rgb(46, 123, 253);
        border-radius: 9px;
    }
```

In order to change the icon when the item is clicked, I used the following code (*actually I don't think the following code matters! If you want to learn more you can continue*):

```
def change_icon(self):
    icon_list = ['resources-inverted/all_music.png', 'resources-inverted/favourite_music.png',
                 'resources-inverted/recommended.png',
                 'resources-inverted/MV.png', 'resources-inverted/bilibili.png']
    index = self.ui.listWidget.currentRow()
    img = QImage(icon_list[index])
    pixmap = QPixmap(img)
    fit_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(23, 23, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,
                               Qt.SmoothTransformation)
    self.ui.listWidget.item(index).setIcon(fit_pixmap)
    self.ui.listWidget.setIconSize(QSize(23, 23))
    self.set_list_icon(exception=index)
```

`self.set_list_icon` is a function that sets all the icons for the QListWidget. It takes in an argument exception which tells the function which row of the QListWidget it should skip. The reason why I called this function at the end of the `change_color` function is that if you don't call such a function, when you click on another item in the QListWidget, the last item's icon color will remain white. But rather, we want to keep the icon's color blue when not selected.

The full project is at:https://github.com/Zhu-Aemon/music_gallery, including all the .png files, the .ui file and all the code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you include the white icon png in your question so I can test it to see If I can reproduce, also have you tried making the icon white on a white background to see if it is still light blue? It looks more like a grey color than blue to me.

Comment: While subtle and not always consistent, the common standard of selected items is to *shade* the contents using the selection color. For instance, on Windows' Explorer, if you click on an icon you'll probably see a "blu-ish" version of the icon (assuming that the system palette uses a shade of blue for selections). Frankly, I don't see it that bad, even in your screenshot. If you really want to override that behavior, then you'll probably need a custom delegate.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for your attention. The whole project is at https://github.com/Zhu-Aemon/music_gallery. You can download all the .png files there

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).